# matching file format using glob in nodejs

Tags: node.js, glob

I am not able to show message *'File not found !'* using glob . here I am using glob to matching file format. if file is available in the directory it is working fine.
but if not available it is nothing showing 'file not found'.
I noticed that  if condition `if (err)` is always false , so that it always shows *'File found'* whether it is available or not !

```
const glob = require('glob');

value1='./**/**.NIC.2*'  //file format like 

if (value1){
    const fs = require("fs");
    glob(value1, function (err, files) {
        
         if (err) {
             console.log('File Not Found !');
           }
         else  { 
                files.forEach(path => {
                   console.log('File  Found !');
                   console.log('File Path => ' +path);
                   var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                    input: require('fs').createReadStream(path),
                   });
                   var lineCounter = 0; var wantedLines = [];
                   lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
                     lineCounter++;
                     wantedLines.push(line);
                     if(lineCounter==1){
                         lineReader.close();}
                    });
                   lineReader.on('close', function() {
                     var obj = wantedLines;
                     a=JSON.stringify(obj);
                     b=a.replace(/\s/g, "");
                     function2(b);
                    });
        });       
    }});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error when the pattern doesn't match anything. If you want to check if the pattern didn't match any files, you should check the length of the `files` argument. If it's zero, then there were no matches and you can act accordingly.

```
if (err) {
  console.error('An error occurred!', e);
} else if (files.length === 0) {
  console.log('File Not Found !');
} else {
  files.forEach(…)
}
```

Comment: oops, I was so closed . i tried with files.length is NULL
Thank you